# How do you cut off text after a certain amount of characters in PHP?

Tags: php, string, strip

I have two string that i want to limit to lets say the first 25 characters for example. Is there a way to cut off text after the 25th character and add a ... to the end of the string?

So  '12345678901234567890abcdefg'
would turn into '12345678901234567890abcde...' where 'fg' is cut off.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->truncate(25)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L233) or [`s($str)->truncateSafely(25)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L246) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str). Both variants are Unicode-safe and the second avoids breaking any words.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

May I make a modification to pallan's code?

```
$truncated = (strlen($string) > 20) ? substr($string, 0, 20) . '...' : $string;
```

This doesn't add the '...' if it is shorter.

Comment: i know that this answer is 7 years old but all the people who are looking answer to this question need to be aware that if you using utf8 encodind you need to replace strlen function with mb_strlen and substr function with mb_substr

Answer (score 10):

Really quickly,

```
$truncated = substr('12345678901234567890abcdefg', 0, 20) . '...'
```

Comment: can you tell me how to only add the ... if it is past 20 characters?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241224/how-do-you-cut-off-text-after-a-certain-amount-of-characters-in-php/1241263#1241263

Answer (score 10):

To avoid cutting right in the middle of a word, you might want to try the [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/wordwrap) function ; something like this, I suppose, could do :

```
$str = "this is a long string that should be cut in the middle of the first 'that'";
$wrapped = wordwrap($str, 25);
var_dump($wrapped);

$lines = explode("\n", $wrapped);
var_dump($lines);

$new_str = $lines[0] . '...';
var_dump($new_str);
```

`$wrapped` will contain :

```
string 'this is a long string
that should be cut in the
middle of the first
'that'' (length=74)
```

The `$lines` array will be like :

```
array
  0 => string 'this is a long string' (length=21)
  1 => string 'that should be cut in the' (length=25)
  2 => string 'middle of the first' (length=19)
  3 => string ''that'' (length=6)
```

And, finally, your `$new_string` :

```
string 'this is a long string' (length=21)
```

With a substr, like this :

```
var_dump(substr($str, 0, 25) . '...');
```

You'd have gotten :

```
string 'this is a long string tha...' (length=28)
```

Which doesn't look that nice :-(

Still, have fun !

Answer (score 8):

This one is short and takes word boundary into account, it doesn't use loops which makes it very efficient

```
function truncate($str, $chars, $end = '...') {
    if (strlen($str) <= $chars) return $str;
    $new = substr($str, 0, $chars + 1);
    return substr($new, 0, strrpos($new, ' ')) . $end;
}
```

Usage:

```
truncate('My string', 5); //returns: My...
```

Answer (score 6):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php
*(PHP 4 >= 4.0.6, PHP 5, PHP 7)*

```
<?php
echo mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10, "...");
echo "<br />";
echo mb_strimwidth("Hello", 0, 10, "...");
?>
```

output:

```
Hello W...
Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$words=explode(' ', $string);
for($ii = 0,$j=0; $ii< 5 && $j < sizeof($words) ;$j++){
    $ii += strlen($words[$j]);
    $intro= $words[$j]. " ";    
}
$intro.= "...";
```

I know its to late, but if anyone else is returning to this page, this will do,

Answer (score 1):

[substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function is the right one for you

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) method.

```
$s = substr($input, 0, 25);
```

This will get you the first chuck of the string and then you can append whatever you'd like to the end.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Pascal MARTIN's answer, with some additional improvements. Because;

1 - "PHP wordwrap", respects word boundaries automatically

2 - If your string contains a word more than 25 chars(aagh, so there is nothing to do) you can force "PHP wordwrap" to cut word.(improvement)

3 -  If your string is shorter than 25 chars, then "..." will seem ugly after a complete sentence.(improvement)

```
$str = "This string might be longer than 25 chars, or might not!";
// we are forcing to cut long words...
$wrapped = wordwrap($str, 25, "\n", 1);
var_dump($wrapped);

$lines = explode("\n", $wrapped);
var_dump($lines);

// if our $str is shorter than 25, there will be no $lines[1]
(array_key_exists('1', $lines)) ? $suffix = '...' : $suffix = '';
$new_str = $lines[0] . $suffix;
var_dump($new_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo substr('12345678901234567890abcdefg', 0, 20) . '...' ?>
```

http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo substr($str,0,25)."...";
```

Would do the trick, but if you are dealing with words, you might want to cut off on word boundries so you don't have partial word doig this: The quick bl...

So to do that (crude off the top of my head):

```
$words = split(" ", strlen($str));

for($i = 0,$j=0; $i< 25 && $j < sizeof($words) ;$j++)
{
    $i += strlen($words[$j]);
    echo $words[$j]. " ";    
}
echo "...";
```